# Zip file path separator

Tags: zip

I am delivering zip files to a company that has a Unix environment and they tell me that the path separator is wrong. I have found a solution that works but when i put it into production the path separator is wrong again.

Is it possible for me to see which path separator a zip-file has when i am using a Windows environment?

No matter how i have tried to open the file the path separator shows up the same even if i know that one file has backslash and another has forward slash i cannot tell them apart.**strong text**

Comment: The path separator in a ZIP file is `'/'`. If you're not delivering that you're wrong, and the target platform has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The target platform has a lot to do with it seing as you will not know that there is an error if the zip file is opened in a windows environment.

Comment: Merely opening a correctly built ZIP file with `/` path separators does not cause an error on any platform.

Answer (score 4):

The path separator in a zip file MUST always be `/`. Here is what the spec ([APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)) for zip files says

```
   4.4.17.1 The name of the file, with optional relative path.
   The path stored MUST NOT contain a drive or
   device letter, or a leading slash.  All slashes
   MUST be forward slashes '/' as opposed to
   backwards slashes '\' for compatibility with Amiga
   and UNIX file systems etc.  If input came from standard
   input, there is no file name field.
```

On Windows the unzip program will transform paths with `/` into native windows paths that use `\`.

To view what path separator is actually being used inside the zip file, you could try running [zipdetails](https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails/blob/main/bin/zipdetails) on it. The `Filename` fields show what is actually being stored internally in the file. The zip file below has a single file `tmp/abc`

```
$ zipdetails /tmp/abc.zip 

0000 LOCAL HEADER #1       04034B50
0004 Extract Zip Spec      0A '1.0'
0005 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
0006 General Purpose Flag  0000
0008 Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
000A Last Mod Time         505246C0 'Tue Feb 18 08:54:00 2020'
000E CRC                   4788814E
0012 Compressed Length     00000004
0016 Uncompressed Length   00000004
001A Filename Length       0007
001C Extra Length          001C
001E Filename              'tmp/abc'
0025 Extra ID #0001        5455 'UT: Extended Timestamp'
0027   Length              0009
0029   Flags               '03 mod access'
002A   Mod Time            5E4BA627 'Tue Feb 18 08:53:59 2020'
002E   Access Time         5E4BA627 'Tue Feb 18 08:53:59 2020'
0032 Extra ID #0002        7875 'ux: Unix Extra Type 3'
0034   Length              000B
0036   Version             01
0037   UID Size            04
0038   UID                 0000245B
003C   GID Size            04
003D   GID                 00005208
0041 PAYLOAD               abc.

0045 CENTRAL HEADER #1     02014B50
0049 Created Zip Spec      1E '3.0'
004A Created OS            03 'Unix'
004B Extract Zip Spec      0A '1.0'
004C Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
004D General Purpose Flag  0000
004F Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
0051 Last Mod Time         505246C0 'Tue Feb 18 08:54:00 2020'
0055 CRC                   4788814E
0059 Compressed Length     00000004
005D Uncompressed Length   00000004
0061 Filename Length       0007
0063 Extra Length          0018
0065 Comment Length        0000
0067 Disk Start            0000
0069 Int File Attributes   0001
     [Bit 0]               1 Text Data
006B Ext File Attributes   81A40000
006F Local Header Offset   00000000
0073 Filename              'tmp/abc'
007A Extra ID #0001        5455 'UT: Extended Timestamp'
007C   Length              0005
007E   Flags               '03 mod access'
007F   Mod Time            5E4BA627 'Tue Feb 18 08:53:59 2020'
0083 Extra ID #0002        7875 'ux: Unix Extra Type 3'
0085   Length              000B
0087   Version             01
0088   UID Size            04
0089   UID                 0000245B
008D   GID Size            04
008E   GID                 00005208

0092 END CENTRAL HEADER    06054B50
0096 Number of this disk   0000
0098 Central Dir Disk no   0000
009A Entries in this disk  0001
009C Total Entries         0001
009E Size of Central Dir   0000004D
00A2 Offset to Central Dir 00000045
00A6 Comment Length        0000
Done
```

Comment: Thanks for the zipdetails - i will look into that.
As for the separator it is apparantly a well known problem when zipping from Powershell that it uses backslash instead of the correct forward slash - i did not know that until the Unix guy told me it was wrong

Comment: This looks like the Powershell bug https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/48

Comment: The solution in the link does not make my zip-files correct. I have changed to a 7zip approach via Powershell this works.
The Zipdetails worked like a charm once i figured out how to execute it (i have absolutely no perl experience.
Thanks for the help